# Flow through flattened tube

Tags: fluid-mechanics

Is there an analytical solution for the Navier Stokes equation for flow through a flattened tube ( flat plate in the center and semicircular lobes at the end).[image]

Comment: What have you searched for so far? Have you looked for Coefficients of discharge for orifices for example?

Comment: I am looking for the velocity profile which would help to calculate shear stress on the wall.

Comment: So, laminar, critical or turbulent flow? You need to provide more info to help us.

Comment: currently, I need the solution for the fully developed laminar case. Thank you very much.

Comment: there are more likely to be analytic solutions for an elliptic shape. Search on that if you think appropriate.

Comment: Thank you for your support, I have got the literature which has the solution. please refer to the link below.  https://link.aps.org/doi/10.1103/PhysRevFluids.1.024001